# Transfer google sheet rows to another sheet based on cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.
I am looking at transferring rows of data into a new spreadsheet based on a cells value.
I have found some examples myself, but not entirely able to make it work for my exact needs. If I have overlooked any previously answered questions, please point me in the right direction. The closest I have been able to achieve is my current code.

I am looking at copying the data in columns A-E when E = "Y" from COPY sheet into PASTE sheet - examples of the sheets are below.
My current issue is that, its copying all the data, even if D isn't "Y", and copying it for every instance of "Y".
So if I have 3 "Y"s in column E then it is copied over 3 times. 
[Copy From this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JGxaHjOeCfQsaNWa2vxE1K7ndVLYgH6GCwVcllUI6jo/edit#gid=0)
[Paste to this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxR-L2-Tj7slZQ0NMbQl0-JXZ8iVO59410ccVNZk7Ys/edit#gid=0)

```js
function transfer() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('COPY'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('A2:E'); 
 var data = range.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i <data.length; ++i){
   var row = data[i];
   var check = row[4];
 
   var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qxR-L2-Tj7slZQ0NMbQl0-JXZ8iVO59410ccVNZk7Ys");
   var ts = tss.getSheetByName('PASTE');
   
   if (check == "Y") {
     ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in the answer try replacing `ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);` with `ts.appendRow(row)`

Comment: @Umair - Thank you for the help with this answer. Can you see how the script can be improved as it takes awhile to run

Comment: Can you post a new question for that ? I had love to answer then.

Comment: @umair Hey - I have asked a new question if you wanted to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'data' variable stores all values from the source sheet, so calling setValues(data) will transfer everything to the target sheet. For simplicity, you can substitute that with:

```
ts.appendRow(row);
```

Another issue is how you are calling the 'getRange()' method:

```
sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
```

In your case, the number of rows is equal to data.length whereas it must be 1 as you only need to copy one row.

Comment: Thank you! This has worked. I wasn't sure how to add it in at first but another comment helped me with this.
I'm worried that it is a bit slow as I will be looking to copy and paste higher amounts of data.

Comment: if you need to process a large amount of data, you should first filter the values array and then write to the target spreadsheet in a single call (targetRange.setValues(filteredValues)). The number of rows would be equal to filteredValues.length. Looping over individual rows would indeed be very slow performance-wise because of multiple calls.